# Multipath - what is the differences between /dev/mapper/mpathxx and /dev/mapper/mpathxx1?

Tags: linux, disk

For every multipath disk label in `/dev/mapper` I have another with 1 in the end. Are they the same? is there some relationship?

For example:

`/dev/mapper/mpathaj` and `/dev/mapper/mpathaj1`
or
`/dev/mapper/mpathai` and `/dev/mapper/mpathai1`

when I issue the command `od --read-bytes=128 --format=c /dev/mapper/mpathai`, the disk seems clean:

```
[root@server02 ~]# od --read-bytes=128 --format=c /dev/mapper/mpathai
0000000  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
*
0000200
```

But the other with 1 in the end show some rows:

```
[root@server02 ~]# od --read-bytes=128 --format=c /dev/mapper/mpathai1
0000000 001 202 001 001  \0  \0  \0  \0 003  \0  \0 200 220   .   5 213
0000020  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000120   3  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
   some characters I needed to remove to don't show costumer content.
0000160  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000200
```

That happen to every disk. One is clean and the other no.

And, the reason I am asking it: Can I lost one (mpathaj) without lost the other (mpathaj1)? I've seen they point to different `/dev/dm-xx`.

ie: `/dev/mapper/mpathaj` is `/dev/dm-18` and `/dev/mapper/mpathaj1` is `/dev/dm-19`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that `/dev/mapper/mpathai` to be the whole disk/LUN, and `/dev/mapper/mpathai1` the first partition on that disk/LUN. But it also could be something like a LUKS encryption layer with a confusingly chosen name.

On device-mapper based devices (multipaths, encrypted disks, software RAID...), partition detection is done in userspace (often via the command `kpartx`), and a new device-mapper entry (`/dev/dm-<number>`) is created for each of them.

The only way to be sure would be to use `dmsetup ls` and/or `dmsetup table` as root to view the mappings and see their relations to each other.

On a modern Linux system, you might begin with `dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname`: it's probably the easiest way to visualize the relationships between the different device-mapper entries, if there are any.

Unfortunately, the `dmsetup ls --tree` listing won't include the type of mapping, so you may still need to refer to `dmsetup table` to identify the type: if the mapping of `mpathai1` is of type `linear` and refers to the `mpathai` device by major:minor numbers, then `mpathai1` is a linear sub-mapping of `mpathai`, which usually means it's a partition within the disk device.

If `mpathai1` is of type `crypt`, then `mpathai` could be an encrypted disk (LUKS or some other method that is understood by `cryptsetup`), which has been configured to have the decrypted view of the device appear as `mpathai1` whenever encryption is unlocked. In other words, the encryption would be unlocked with a command like:

```
cryptsetup open /dev/mapper/mpathai mpathai1 --type <luks,loopaes,tcrypt,bitlk...>
```

If encryption is used, I would expect `/etc/crypttab` to also mention the device(s).

If you can't identify the mapping type on your own, please post the output of e.g. `dmsetup table mpathai1` and `dmsetup table mpathaj1`.

If `mpathaj1` is a partition of `mpathaj`, you could lose `mpathaj1` by e.g. corrupting/overwriting the partition table. If the partition table no longer has a valid entry for the `mpathaj1` partition, the system would no longer show it, even if the underlying disk `mpathaj` is 100% fine.

The same is true if `mpathaj1` is the decrypted view of encrypted `mpathaj`, then if the encryption key (e.g. the encrypted master key within the LUKS header) is lost for any reason, you will no longer be able to unlock the encryption, and then `mpathaj1` and all data within it are effectively lost to you.

Comment: You are right, it's a partition! but can I lose the mpathaj and not lose the mpathaj1 (partition)? I mean, overwrite mpathaj with redirect command (>)

Comment: Since the partition is just a limited portion of the whole-disk device, if you write to `mpathaj` as much data as will fit, you will definitely overwrite everything that was in `mpathaj1`. But if you write less than 1 MiB, you might lose nothing but the partition table, which may be easy to recover with `testdisk`; most modern partitioning tools will place the beginning of the first partition exactly 1 MiB away from the beginning of the disk.

Comment: In this case, it was only some characters (maybe 10 or 15) and redirected with > to the device (the one without 1 in the end). This has happened yesterday, and no trouble until now. As I 've posted, the others seems clean as well, only the partition has data. Thanks for the help.

Comment: 10 or 15 characters starting from the beginning of the disk would only overwrite the beginning of the Master Boot Record boot code - and if it's not your boot disk, the boot code area (the first 446 bytes) is not used at all. The MBR-style partition table is in the last 68 bytes of the first 512-byte block. If you used GPT partitioning instead, the entire block #0 would be ignored by Linux as soon as it detected a valid GPT partition table starting from block #1... or the backup GPT partition table at the very last blocks on the disk.